# Can I get away from pandas iteration if each row/column needs to be calcualted in a specific order?

Tags: python, pandas

Simple example would be as follows:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 0, 0, 0], 'col2': [0, 'a', 'a', 0], 'col3': [0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[0, 1, 2, 3])



for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    
    if i >0:
        df.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[i-1,2]
    if df.iloc[i,1] == 'a':
        df.iloc[i,2] = df.iloc[i,0]+1
    else:
        df.iloc[i,2] = df.iloc[i,0]
```

In the above example, col3 is dependent on col1 and col2, and col1 is dependent on the previous col3. As far as I can tell this is not something you can use vectorized functions for. I initially wrote something like this iterate through a pandas dataframe of 6 columns (dependent on each other like in the above example) `~500,000` rows, and it took `2-3 minutes` to run each time. I then rewrote it to convert the dataframe in a a numpy array, iterate through those, and then convert back to pandas dataframe, and that shortened the time to `~10 seconds`. I'm interested in making this even faster as I will be running it a lot.

Comment: `As far as I can tell this is not something you can use vectorized functions for.` Seems like you could write it as `(df['col2'] == 'a').cumsum() + df['col1'][0]` to calculate col3. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: That solution works for the example above, but the problem I have is more complicated than the simplified version above and so that wouldn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried converting into numpy arrays, then using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to run the loop?

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick, down to just over 1 second now.